# Is it legal to simplify $\frac{x^2}{|x|}$ to $|x|$?

Tags: continuity, absolute-value, linear-control

My classmates and I have been locked in a debate on whether this simplification is allowed (we are linearizing a continuous time system about an equilibrium solution at $x=0$).

I say it is not allowed because doing so changes the domain of the expression, but others say it should be ok because representing $x^2$ as $|x||x|$ is mathematically allowed.

The answer to this question determines whether the nonlinear system can be linearized about this solution, so we are very keen to find out which camp is correct!

Comment: As functions, $x^2/|x|$ is not defined at $0$, while $|x|$ is; so the function $f(x)=x^2/|x|$ and the function $g(x) = |x|$ are different functions: they have different domains. On the nonzero reals they take the same values, but you must be careful about that different domains. Just like $f(x)=x/x$ is not the same as $g(x)=1$, because they have different domains.

Comment: It is ok to simplify that way. It would not be ok to replace $|x|$ by ${x^2 \over |x|}$.

Comment: The comment above answers the question, but $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}x^2/|x|=|x|$. It might be interesting to discuss about the nonlinear system and whether that is a valid expansion or not.